# Transferir lista para Arquivo binário em python

Tags: python-3.x

Bom dia programadores. Preciso colocar uma lista em um arquivo binário mas está apresentando erro.

```
 lista = [-1, 333.0, -1, 333.0, 10, 8.0, 45, -66.5999984741211, 12, -44.70000076293945]
```

Código:

```
  open("saida.bin", "wb") as arq1:
  for x in lista:
      arq1.write(struct.pack('=i', x))
      arq1.write(struct.pack('=f', x))
  arq1.close()
```

erro:

```
arq1.write(struct.pack('=i', x))
struct.error: required argument is not an integer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro te diz exatamente qual é o problema. Quando você faz

```
arq1.write(struct.pack('=i', x))
```

Está tentando botar `x` em um espaço `int` (como indicado pelo `=i`), quer dizer, um número inteiro. Uma observação cuidadosa da lista nos revela que alguns dos valores não são inteiros (333.0, -66.59, etc).

Você também está adicionando os mesmos valores como `float`, quer dizer, números de ponto flutuante (não inteiros) na linha abaixo disso.

Como um `float` pode assumir um valor inteiro mas um `int` não pode assumir um valor fracionário, o que eu recomendaria é simplesmente remover a linha

```
arq1.write(struct.pack('=i', x))
```

Assim, seus números vão ser guardados como float e você pode retorná-los a uma lista normalmente:

```
with open('saida.bin', 'rb') as f:
    print(struct.unpack('=10f', f.read()))
# (-1.0, 333.0, -1.0, 333.0, 10.0, 8.0, 45.0, -66.5999984741211, 12.0, -44.70000076293945)
```

Se for necessário manter o formato de número inteiro para sua aplicação, então você vai ter que verificar o tipo da variável antes de inseri-la no struct.

```
with open("saida.bin", "wb") as arq1:
    for x in lista:
        if isinstance(x, int):
            arq1.write(struct.pack('=i', x))
        elif isinstance(x, float):
            arq1.write(struct.pack('=f', x))
        else:
            raise TypeError('x não é int nem float!')
```

Mas aí você tem outros problemas pra resolver porque você também tem que saber o tipo da variável ao dar `unpack`. Assim, ou você deve ter certeza de que os itens da lista têm seus tipos em uma certa ordem, ou guardar junto alguma informação sobre qual elemento tem qual tipo, ou deve armazená-los separadamente.

Comment: Obrigado pedro pela resposta, amigo tem como eu fazer uma interação e trocar os valores dessa lista no caso se for inteiro colocar -1 e se for float colocar 999.0 diretamente dentro do arquivo binario.